# Minimum Configuration for a WCF service to host

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class library project which has an interface and an implemented service class with Service and Data Contracts.

I have built those to dlls and now I have created an empty web application and referenced those assemblies. I want this web application to host the service.

What minimum Web configurations do I need to make the service up and running.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, the _WCF Service Application_ project template will do just that for you.

Comment: You can add a *.svc page to the application with the appropriate markup, and if you're fine with `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP 1.1) and the default settings for that binding you don't need to add anything to the config file - you will get default endpoints, bindings and behaviors.

Comment: I can do the job with above advice but the question still lies how to do the same without a physical svc file.

Comment: To be honest, googling for 'basic wcf host' will suffice (2 first links actually)